# Close browser from java code using specific url address

Tags: java, browser, using

1) I want to close specific browser tab using url address from my java code. As it is a client server applicaiton. I want to close  browser tab using url address from my client application

The server side will have a jar that will communicate with client request and take the url from client and close the browser running in the server machine according the url address.

2) I want to close my firefox or chrome browser from my java code also. I don't want to kill process but shut down browser normally.

**I need this solution for ubuntu os.

Hope for your response.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To enable us to help you better, could you please update your question with what research you've already done on your own, such as: code that you've tried or APIs and frameworks you've looked at.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call a javascript to close the client's browser from your javascode.
This is called reverse Ajax. You can achieve by using DWR framework.
This a powerful API which help you to call Java from Javascipt and vice versa.

By using this you can filter clients browser that are onto a specific URL.

And this solution is not a OS specific it will work fine for every OS platform.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I understood correctly your reply then I think my problem is to close browser or browser tab from java jar file. In that case I think I need something like close unix command to close the browser. I can kill the process but that I don't want I just want to close the browser normally.

Comment: no it will use a javascript code to be executed ie OS independent .
    window.close();

Comment: here I have to close the browser from my java jar. I dont have any control of the browser how I will call window.close. Do you have some example?

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code to filter on the basis of login user.
There you have to change the condition accordingly.

```
WebContext webContext = WebContextFactory.get();
Collection<ScriptSession> ss = webContext.getAllScriptSessions();
        for (ScriptSession s : ss) {
            if (s.getAttribute("uname")!=null && s.getAttribute("uname").equals(to)) {
                Util util = new Util(s);
                ScriptBuffer sc= new ScriptBuffer();
                sc.appendScript("window.close()");
                util.addScript(sc);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Amit again. But when I run this code in my application I got null pointer exception because webContext is null. Do you have some idea why its get null references?

Comment: yes Asraful,
you wont be able to run he code directly.
You have to include DWR jar in your application.
Please google out how to use DWR.
Here is the link.
http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html

Comment: Yes I added the dwr.jar before running the application.

Comment: simultniusly you have to make changes in application's config files too.
All of this are already present in the link provided

Comment: I checked and its for web application but my application is java application not web application. Can I also use it in my windows java application.

Comment: No it can't be used in system based applications.