# Open URL with Java, then close the browser

Tags: java

I'd like to open an URL in the default browser using Java. So I am doing what the answer in this question says: [Open a link in browser with java button?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10967451/555690)

It works. However, I want to automatically close that browser after some 10 seconds have passed (from Java). This is for Windows machines.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015463/close-browser-from-java-code-using-specific-url-address or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075997/closing-a-web-browser-for-a-specific-url-from-the-java-program

Answer (score 0):

Start the process with:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"explorer", "http://google.pl"});
```

and after your 10 sec call:

```
    p.destroy();
```

Comment: Is killing a process like that not bad ? Eg. If the web browser wants to delete cookies on exit, will killing the browser process not prevent this ? Firefox shows a "restore tabs on crash" when it was killed, would this not have the same effect ?

Comment: Yes, the process will be killed. But In pure java you have only this way.