# Quitting Browser from Java

Tags: java, browser

I have this code to open a browser every 5 seconds, but I can't get it to close after 5 seconds.
Can you guys give me any hints? Thanks a lot!

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class Browser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    String url = "www.google.com";

    int x = 5;
    while (x < 8)
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000); // define after how many milliseconds new tab will be opened

        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            try {
                desktop.browse(new URI(url));
            } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Thread.sleep(5000); // define how long video will be played in milliseconds

            }
        } else {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                runtime.exec("xdg-open " + url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Thread.sleep(5000); // define how long video will be played in milliseconds

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015463/close-browser-from-java-code-using-specific-url-address or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075997/closing-a-web-browser-for-a-specific-url-from-the-java-program

Comment: Thanks a lot! Acc. to second link it seems like you can't do it from the desktop.browse, need to rework the script.